# Why can't you rename the body property?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift-protocols

In swiftUI, in order to conform to the View protocol, the conforming struct has to implement the body property (specifically, its getter, since body property is read-only).

Can I change the name of body property to something else, say presentation?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var presentation: some View {
        Button("Hello SwiftUI!") {
            
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't work. I get 'Type 'ContentView' does not conform to protocol 'View'.

In UIKit, when conforming to the UIApplicationDelegate protocol, I was able to change the name of the UIWindow variable. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623056-window) has the name 'window', but when conforming, I changed it to mainWindow and things worked.

Why can't I change the name of body property of a swiftUI view? Am I missing something?

Comment: "Am I missing something?"

What a protocol is, perhaps?

Comment: Read about what a protocol is in [The Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html) book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I change the name of body property to something else

No. A protocol's requirements are required. To conform, you must obey them to the letter.

> when conforming to the UIApplicationDelegate protocol, I was able to change the name of the UIWindow variable

That variable isn't a requirement. Note the marking `optional` on the page you yourself linked to.